Accessing a service inside a mesh from another application outside the mesh but still within the same cluster
I have two applications:

Application A is outside the service mesh. Under namespace ns-outside-mesh. Its pod does not have any sidecar.
Application B is inside the service mesh. Under namespace ns-inside-mesh. Its pod has the Istio proxy sidecar.

Both applications are in the same cluster. There is no Ingress involved. They are all in-cluster communications.
I ssh-ed into Application A and curl-ed Service B, which is the service associated to Application B with command curl serviceB.ns-inside-mesh.svc. It gives me 403 rbac access denied, which is expected because Pod A does not have any Istio proxy sidecar which will embed the request with the necessary authorization information.
What should I do to let Application A access Application B? I don't want to use Istio Gateway because I don't want to expose this application publicly. I just want to expose it to other applications within the same cluster but outside the service mesh.

If you're using STRICT mode for mTLS this is not possible. You have to change to PERMISSIVE mode or, alternatively if you're using STRICT mode, configure the PeerAuth to disable mTLS at port level for a given workload.
Edit: Or the other way around, set global mTLS to PERMISSIVE and then enable in the Destination Rule ISTIO_MUTUAL per hostname for the ones you don't want to access from a sidecar app.
